# How to show/get 'products' in twig/controller

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new to PHP and Symfony2 but I'm learning my way.

I am struggling with getting my products associated with my user's cart to be shown on a 'show cart' page.

These are my associations:

[image: These are my associations]

This is my `showCartAction` function:

```
/**
 * Shows Empty Cart
 *
 * @Route("/showCart", name="product_showCart")
 * @METHOD("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showCartAction(Request $request) {

// --------------------------- show only what the user added to their cart --------------------------- //
// show products associated with userCartID

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    // $id = $this->getId();
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $cart = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:UserCart')->findOneBy(['user' => $this->getUser()], $submitted=NULL);

    if (!$cart) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'ERROR: No product found for id '
        );
    }

    $totalCostOfAllProducts = 0;

    if (empty($price) && empty($quantity) && empty($totalCostOfAllProducts) && empty($cartArray)) {
        $price = 0; $quantity = 0; $totalCostOfAllProducts = 0; $cartArray = [];
    }

    return array(
        // 'user'  => $user,
        // 'products' => $cart->getProduct(),   // for :Quantity
        // 'products' => $cart->getUserCart(),   // for :Quantity
        'user' => $cart->getUser(),         // for :UserCart
        'quantity' => $cart->getQuantities(),         // for :UserCart
        // 'product' => $->getProduct(),         // for :UserCart
        'totalCostOfAllProducts'    => $totalCostOfAllProducts,
    );
}
```

This is the twig file:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price Per Unit</th>
                    <th>Remove Product</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            {% for key, quantities in quantity %}  

                    <tr>
                    {#  <td>{{ key }}</td> <!--Product-->    #}
                        <td>{{ quantity.product }}</td> <!--Product-->   
                        <td>
                            <input class="spinner" value="0" style="width:30px">
                        </td> <!--Quantity-->
                    {#  <td>${{ product.price }}</td> <!--Price Per Unit-->   #}
                        <td>
                            <a href="{{ path('product_remove', {'id': key }) }}">
                                <button name="REMOVE" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="removeButton">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </button>
                            </a>
                        </td><!--Remove--> 
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}      
            </tbody>
        </table> <!--top table-->
```

Which shows nothing, meaning no 'products' in the page.

[image: screenshot of page]

EDIT: var dump of quantities:

```
ProductController.php on line 428:
PersistentCollection {#1179 ▼
  -snapshot: []
  -owner: UserCart {#1161 ▼
    -id: 3
    -timestamp: null
    -submitted: null
    -user: User {#1053 ▶}
    -quantities: PersistentCollection {#1179}
  }
  -association: array:15 [ …15]
  -em: EntityManager {#68 …10}
  -backRefFieldName: "userCart"
  -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#1162 …}
  -isDirty: false
  -initialized: false
  -coll: ArrayCollection {#1180 ▶}
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug the data you sent to your view (by doing for example a `var_dump($cart->getQuantities()`) in your controller?

Comment: yes, I will include that in an edit above so everyone can see. Myabe you can help decipher what is wrong with it?

Comment: then I get Method "user" for object "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" does not exist... But isn't a collection and an array basically the same thing. and in order to access the collection I need to use a loop?

Answer (score 0):

For one you are mixing up your variable names.

```
# showCartAction
return array(
        ...
        'quantity' => $cart->getQuantities()
        ...       
);

# showcart.html.twig
{% for key, quantities in quantity %}  
     ...
     <td>{{ quantity.product }}</td> 
     ...
{% endfor %}
```

In your template 'quantity' is your collection of quantities in your cart, while 'quantities' is one of these items in your for loop.
Thus 'quantity' has no product attribute, but 'quantities' should have it (depending on your Entity for Quantity, probably as foreign key):
    # showcart.html.twig
    {{ quantities.product }}

Or even better label the array returned by your action 'quantities' to keep your code more readable.

```
# showCartAction
$quantities = $cart->getQuantities();
return array(
  'quantities' => $quantities;
)

# showcart.html.twig
{% for key, quantity in quantities %}  
     ...
     <td>{{ quantity.product }}</td> 
     ...
{% endfor %}
```

Also your quantity-collection appears to be empty.
Check the collection size inside your template:

```
# showcart.html.twig
{{ dump(quantities|length) }}
```

Either there is something off with your ORM configuration or you didnt load any fixtures into your project.

Some minor advice:
Keep your controller actions slim.
Outsource getting your cart from the model along with exception handling (use 'try..catch' instead of 'if' there) to an extra method.
Use app_dev.php for development. It's more strict and will rather show detailed error messages instead of showing blank tables.